# Can we improve the given 3x3 matrix-vector multiplication further? Or is there a better way?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

Suppose we have 
$$ \begin{bmatrix} a & 2c & 2b \\ b & a & 2c \\ c & b & a\end{bmatrix} \times \begin{bmatrix} e \\ f \\g \end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix} B+C+D \\ A+C+E \\A+B+F \end{bmatrix}$$ 
Where 
$$\begin{equation*} \begin{aligned} 
A &= b\big(e+f\big) \\ 
B &= a\big(e+g\big) \\
C &= 2c\big(f+g\big) \\
D &= g\big(-2(c-b)-a\big) \\
E &= f\big(a-(b+2c)\big) \\
F &= e\big((c-b)-a\big)
\end{aligned} \end{equation*}$$

Is there a better solution?

Any improvement or suggestion will be highly appreciated. I mean to decrease the number of operations that are multiplication, addition and/or subtraction.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by a 'better solution'?

Comment: @GuyPaterson-Jones, I mean can we decrease the number of multiplications and/or additions and subtractions further.

Comment: the unknowns are uppercase letters, correct?

Comment: Yes, because we have to compute the correct result

Answer (score 1):

You have six unknowns and three equations, so you are free to choose any value for three of your unknowns.  It is "nicest" to choose the following:

$A=B=C=0$,

$D = ae + 2cf + 2bg$,

$E = be + af + 2cg$,

$F = ce + bf + ag$.

To convince you that anything else would make it worse, let's look at the first two equations in your system,

$ae + 2cf + 2bg = B + C + D$,

$be + af + 2cg = A + C + E$.

Imagine choosing $C$ to be anything other than $0$, in fact, let's do as you chose above, $C=2cf + 2cg$.  But the left side of the first equation does not contain $2cg$, and you had to account for this by giving to $D$ the extra summand $-2cg$.  Similarly, the left side of the second equation does not have $2cf$, and you had to account for this by giving to $E$ the extra summand $-2cf$.

Anything you give to $A$, $B$, or $C$ has to be counteracted by one of your other three variables, so your simplest solution should have these three as $0$.

Comment: I am asking for decreasing the number of operations that are multiplication, addition and/or subtraction.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by this.  You have a system of three equations and need to assign values for the capital letters based on the lowercase letters.  The assignment I gave has the least number of operations.  If these aren't the operations you want to reduce, then I don't understand. Could you explain the full problem?  What variables are unknowns, and which operations exactly are you trying to get rid of?

Comment: If we perform the naive matrix-vector multiplication, then there will be 9 multiplications and 6 additions of double size. By our solution now the same operation can be performed with 6 multiplications, 4 additions, 4 subtractions and 6 additions of double size. So it is possible to reduce our number of operations further?